# How to prevent non-approved 3rd Party SPA access to resource when using OAuth 2.0 for authorisation?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I'm trying to allow access to our publicly facing APIs to approved Single Page Applications only.
We currently use OAuth 2.0 to control access to our APIs.  The high level scenario is that our users will access our publicly available SPA, provide their username and password, and then be able to use the SPA which in turn will be able to use our APIs.

The current best practice for OAuth 2.0 with SPA is to use the authorisation code grant with a client id but **without** the client secret, as obviously an SPA cannot keep any secrets.

My question is how can we prevent a third party SPA from accessing our APIs.  I.e. they could extract the existing client_id from our SPA and request an authorisation code in the same way as our first party SPA.  Assuming they can persuade a user to login they can then access our APIs.
Is the pre-registered redirect URL the only defence in this scenario? If so, does that mean that if we switch to using the resource owner credentials grant for a better user experience (not recommended I know) there would be no protection from third party apps at all?

I've read the various RFCs for OAuth and this page in particular is very useful but doesn't quite answer my question:
https://auth0.com/blog/oauth2-implicit-grant-and-spa/

Comment: Public clients should register their redirect URIs. If a malicious application tries to get an access token, the authorization server should reject the request as the redirect URI is not in the list

Answer (score 2):

Indeed the pre-registered Redirect URI is the only defense mechanism in this case of a public Client when using the so-called Implicit grant type. An attacker may trick the user in starting the flow but will not receive the issued token on a Redirect URL that it controls. This is similar to tricking the user into starting any other login flow.

Since the attacker does not obtain a token (it is still delivered on the intended Redirect URI controlled by the Client) he cannot access your APIs, even if he can persuade the user to login.

When the attacker controls DNS things become more dangerous but that goes for a lot of things outside of OAuth 2.0 as well. In general: delivering tokens to an in-browser app is going to suffer from this type of vulnerability regardless of the protocol used.

Switching to Resource Owner Password Credentials has a lot of drawbacks, including one where the attacker can present an app similar to yours to obtain the username/password (which also block you from upgrading to multi-factor authentication as the other grant types would allow you to).

In summary: there is protection against it although not super strong.

FWIW: the latest OAuth 2.0 best practices suggest that tokens should no longer be directly delivered to the Redirect URI but use an intermediate short-loved one-time usage Authorization Code instead to allow the SPA to get its tokens in an XHR call directly from the token endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.   To check my understanding, even with a pre-registered redirect URL, could an attacker not simpler ignore the redirect but still use the provided authorisation code or token (depending on the grant type in use)?  I'm wondering if I'm missing something very obvious here, but what is to stop a malicoius SPA using the browser fetch AP or XHR to call the authorisation URL with the username, password and stolen Client ID then simply ignore the redirect but extract the auth code from the 302 Location header?

Comment: He may do that for a code that is generated for him, but not for another user

Comment: I'm thinking more of the scenario where a well meaning third party decides to build their own Third Party App.  E.g. lets say Company A builds an SPA that is used by employees in Company B.  A developer in Company B decides he can build something better, and instead of having his new SPA registered with Company A simply calls the Company A authorisation URL, ignores the redirect (is this possible with a legitimate user agent?), extracts the authorisation code, then obtains an access token as per normal OAuith 2.0 flow?  He then persuades his employees to use his newer, better SPA...

Comment: who's to "ignore the redirect" and how would the attacker control that?